# Which accordion WordPress plugin supports Polylang?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm trying to build an FAQ page using accordion UI but all FAQ plugins I tried do not support Polylang. Does anyone know any accordion plugins that do support?

Comment: If you use any translation plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang-supertext/
This must change the text to the supported language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here, https://getshortcodes.com/

IT should work with Polylang since I could translate the FAQ page itself without needing a third party plugin to store my FAQ items